# Tail recursive observable returning function with Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-observable

Suppose I have a service with a method that pings an url until a certain condition is met. After that it returns the result. The whole thing should be built with Observables (to be easily cancellable from outside, so no recursion with Promises or the like).

I tried this which I expected to make a call every second until the condition is met and then return the result.

```js
getData(): Observable<MyData> {
  return this.apiService.get('/url').pipe(
    map((res) => {
      if (...certain condition concerning 'res') {
        return res;
      }
      return timer(1000).pipe(
        map(() => this.getData())
      );
    })
  );
}
```

If I invoke it like this though the apiService is called only once and the result in the subscribe method is resolved right away and is another Observable. There's something definitely wrong that I'm doing, but can't figure out what, probably when returning the delayed recursive call.

```js
getData().subscribe(res => {
  // res is an Observable, I expected an MyData after a delay of at least 1 second
  // as the condition is guaranteed to fail the first time (for testing purposes)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With RxJs recursion often means the use of the `expand` operator.

In your case you could try something like this

```
// condition is a function that returns true if a certain condition on res is met, otherwise false
const condition = (res) => {
   if (...certain condition concerning 'res') {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false
      }
};

function getData() {
  return this.apiService.get('/url').pipe(
    // If the condition is met the Observable stream is completed with no value notified
   // if instead the condition in not met, then the API call is performed again
    expand((res) => {
      return condition(res) ? EMPTY : this.apiService.get('/url').pipe(delay(1000));
    }),
    // this filter condition is optional and its use is to avoid notifying values
    // until the expected one is received
    filter(condition)
  );
}
```

[Here a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kdxnew?file=index.ts) that simulates this logic.